# I need to reset a sum amount each time the group data is executed.

Tags: crystal-reports, reset, formulas

We have the sum of a formula (Sum({@EstHours})-SUM({@ActHours})) that we need to reset to zero, then calculate per phase line. The reset formula is in the same group the Balance formula aforementioned is in. I have also tried placing it in different sections. The ResetBalance formula I've been trying to use is WhilePrintingRecords;
NumberVar Balance:=0;

Comment: By "per phase line" do you mean per group? I'm interpreting this as you're just looking to subtract one group sum from another group sum, is that right?

Comment: 100% correct, Ryan. The amounts per phase (which is a group) is in the phase group's header, and totals (obviously) in the footer.

Comment: I also added a variable definition as Balance={@Balance}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapt this formula to your specific situation:

```
// {@delta}
Sum({@EstHours}, {table.groupingField}) - Sum({@ActHours, {table.groupingField})
```

Add field to `{table.groupingField}`'s group header or footer.